# NestJs - Angular - Deployment strategy

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, nestjs

I've developed a small application for a factory that had a specific need. It's a small application which will be used locally by less than 10 people.

For now, I've my backend and frontend in the same git repository.

Repository structure looks like this

```
--README.md
--.gitignore
--document
--projects
  |--backend        // Nestjs API
  |--frontend       // Angular
```

I've prepared NestJS to serve static files, which means I've configured my Angular builder to work as follow:

*angular.json*

```
...
"options": {
    "outputPath": "../backend/client/dist",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "aot": true,
...
```

My NestJs server is configured to serve static files :

*main.ts*

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
async function bootstrap() {
   const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
   app.enableCors();
   app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
   await app.listen(PORT);
}
...
```

*app.module.ts*

```
imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'client/dist'),
    }),
```

Until today, I used npm with `npm run start:dev`, which allow me to automatically build my database and run the backend server.
Now, I need to deploy my backend and frontend into the same server and build everything.

What is the best approach ?
Should I first build angular into the dist folder, build nestjs .. 
I can only take the dist folder onto the production server right ?

Comment: Are you using NestJs to serve your Angular application ?

Comment: Yes ! My NestJs application is serving my angular client. I've created a script that deploy everything ...

Comment: Are you deploying on linux or windows?

Comment: Also are you using apache?

Comment: The development env is running under Windows, so I've created a little Powershell script that run CLI tool to build everything (Angular, Nest, config) and my prod env is an LXD container running a Nodejs server, using PM2 to manage process

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, it's to build your angular app and copy the files where you serve your frontend. If your app is routed, you also have to configure  a fallback to index.html, you can see how here: [Angular deployement](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

For your nestjs app, you can put it pretty much anywhere on your server and pm2 will serve it on the port 8080. First pull all your files from nestjs and use npm install (you need the node_modules in prod too with nestjs). Then use nest build to build your app. With pm2, you should use main.js to start your api. Then I would look into a proxy reverse configuration to redirect all your api request to 8080. What it does is that if you reach example.com/api you server will understand that it has to redirect to 8080 internaly, so you don't have to open any other port then 80 wich is what you want.

I would also consider to start pm2 on startup of your server and save your pm2 configuration so it start your backend automaticly if you ever restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

I have been through the same process several times and decided to share some basic demo on how to achieve this in the most easy and clean way possible.

My approach is to package both the frontend and backend in docker images on the host server. I also packaged a Jenkins instance that automatically build both Angular and NestJS and reload the docker containers.

You can deploy your app easily and decide to trigger a build on each commit. It will be pushed automatically to your production server.

You can refer to the sample project here:
https://github.com/godardth/typescript-fullstack-boilerplate